# Wordpress Contact Form 7 hack

Tags: php, contact-form-7

I am a php procedural guy who quickly gets lost in Wordpress' complexity and OOO code.  I am trying what I *think* is a simple hack in the Contact Form 7 plugin running on a site and I am not having success.

I am trying to do an exec call in one of Contact Form 7's classes:

> wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/classes.php  (line 549):

```
if ( $send ) {
    exec ("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/record_subscription_change.php  -s $subject -r $recipient -b $body");
    return @wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

Essentially I am trying to call an outside php script and pass variables into it.  I tried creating my own function in `classes.php` and that made Contact Form 7 very unhappy (it just spins when I hit the submit button).

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the right link to the script? Are you sure the script has no errors?

Comment: Are you just trying to work around whatever problem you ran into when you tried adding the function to `classes.php`? If so, I'd suggest trying to deal with that problem rather than trying to fix the workaround.

Comment: Yes I did.  The script prints to stdout using print_r and writes to a log file using error_log.  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/record_subscription_change.php  -s subject -r recipient
Array
(
    [s] => subject
    [r] => recipient
)

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being ownership/permissions.  Wordpress under apache didn't have the permission to execute the script or write to the log file.  Once these permissions were corrected it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hack Contact Form 7 at all, just use a CF7 hook ...

http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/#index=a

> functions.php

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1);
function action_wpcf7_mail_sent($contact_form) { 
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if($submission) {
        $mail_temp = $contact_form->prop('mail');
        $mail = wpcf7_mail_replace_tags($mail_temp);
        $subject = $mail['subject'];
        $recipient = $mail['recipient'];
        $body = $mail['body'];
        exec ("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/record_subscription_change.php  -s $subject -r $recipient -b $body");
    }
    return $contact_form;
}
```